# How can I use few query to DB within router on Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

**I have router and need to fetch data from two different collections. How can I do this without callbacks?**

```
router.get('/menu/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    var product = Product.find({menu: req.params.id}, function(err, products){
        var menu = Menu.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, menu){
            res.render('menu', {  
                user: req.user,
                csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
                current_menu: menu,
                products: products
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It might be worth using promises or `async`/`await` to clean this up. As it stands you're not checking for errors and just blundering along as if everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @tadman said it will be useful to use `async/await` :

```
router.get('/menu/:id', async function(req, res, next) {
   var products= await Product.find({menu: req.params.id}).exec();
   var menu = await Menu.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).exec();
        res.render('menu', {  
            user: req.user,
            csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
            current_menu: menu,
            products: products
        });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you and @tadman! Just one thing: Async functions are not supported by Node versions older than version 7.6